# Merge two queries

Tags: subquery

i need to merge two queries: one lists the sum off all items per month, and one lists the sum of the items YTD.

I used union and it works when 'YTD' is selected in my dropdownlist. However, when i select any other month it give me the results of YTD and the selected month....

The union query so far:

```
SELECT 
    Site.Site_Name 'Site', 
    'YTD' as 'Month_Name',
    Sum(MOT.Total_MR_Count_Received) 'Receiving', 
    Sum(MOT.Total_Line_Item_Count_Received) 'Checking', 
    Sum(MOT.Total_MR_Count_Shipped) 'Shipment Activity'

FROM 
    Metrics_Main 
    INNER JOIN Metrics_MOT MOT ON Metrics_Main.Metrics_Key = MOT.Metrics_Key 
    INNER JOIN Month ON Metrics_Main.Month_Key = Month.Month_Key 
    INNER JOIN Site ON Metrics_Main.Site_Key = Site.Site_Key

group by Site.site_name

union 

SELECT        
    Site.Site_Name 'Site', 
    Month.Month_Name 'Month_Name',          
    sum(MOT.Total_MR_Count_Received) 'Receiving',
    sum(MOT.Total_Line_Item_Count_Received) 'Checking',
    sum(MOT.Total_MR_Count_Shipped) 'Shipment_Activity'

FROM            
    Metrics_Main 
    INNER JOIN Metrics_MOT MOT ON Metrics_Main.Metrics_Key = MOT.Metrics_Key 
    INNER JOIN Month ON Metrics_Main.Month_Key = Month.Month_Key 
    INNER JOIN Site ON Metrics_Main.Site_Key = Site.Site_Key

WHERE        
    Month.Month_Name like @Month_Name

group by Site.site_name, month.month_name
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp. Make sure you that you have the exact same number of columns in the two select queries; so add the "Month_Name" to the first query as well.

Comment: I used union and it works when 'YTD' is selected in my dropdownlist. However, when i select any other month it give me the results of YTD and the selected month....